# How do I to get title, description, image_url of a URL using Ajax like sharing a link on Facebook

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, facebook, share

I am working on a project where if a user submits a URL, it should grab the title, images, and description from that URL and then give an option to change between images.

When submitted it should post those values.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: Come on, that's way too easy. Ok, we know what is should do, but what does it do now? ;)

Comment: please give me the code guys or a link to a tutorial or reference.

Comment: right now the user types in the url, title, description, image url. I wanted to make it more usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook, Google+ gets image, title, description from two known ways.

1) Most of the well-know websites gives og tags. It contains title, description, image 
http://ogp.me/

2) meta tags inside head tag of html will also be published by many sites. You can make use of that also.

For more explanation see the following link.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6745/how-does-facebook-publisher-select-the-image-title-and-content-from-a-shared

Answer (score 1):

I advise that you make a PHP page that parses the information and returns the data to you Ajax function. So to summarize, you'll want to google: "PHP Parsing HTML" and "Ajax PHP Retrieve Data".